# When connected to VPN cannot autocomplete addresses using VPN domain

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, ping, intranet

I am logged in into another company VPN and when I try to browse their intranet I get redirected to an error page since the address is being complented with the incorrect domain.

When I perform `nslookup`:

```
C:\Users\user>nslookup intranet
Server:  intranet.corp.othercompany.com
Address:  1.2.3.4 (sorry I had to change this)

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    intranet.mycompany.com
Address:  192.168.0.1
```

When I ping `intranet`:

```
C:\Users\user>ping intranet

Pinging intranet.mycompany.com [192.168.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=227ms TTL=51
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=227ms TTL=51
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=228ms TTL=51
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=227ms TTL=51

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.1:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 227ms, Maximum = 228ms, Average = 227ms
```

Is it possible to force the domain completion be something like intranet.corp.othercompany.com ?

That would allow me to browse their intranet correctly since there are a lot of references in that page to addresses like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve that by changing my network interface card configuration so DNS will append the domains in the right order. Here is how I managed to achieve that:

- Go to Control Panel, then View Network Status and Tasks, then change adapter settings.
- Right click your Local Area NIC adapter and select Properties
- Select Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) and then select Properties
- On General tab select Advanced
- On DNS tab select "Append these DNS suffixes (in order):
- Click Add and add the "`corp.othercompany.com`" suffix
- Click Add again and add "`mycompany.com`" suffix
- Unmark Register this connection's address in DNS

That should allow you to access the domains for the othercompany as well as the ones on mycompany.